# LP constraint problem with scipy

Tags: graph, scipy

For this graph and its [vertex cover](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertex_cover) I try to compare the LP solution with the optimal and the rounded solution.

[image]

```
from scipy.optimize import linprog
obj = [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
lhs_ineq = [[ -1,  -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[ -1,  0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0],[ 0,  -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0],[ 0,  -1, 0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0],[ 0,  0, -1, -1, 0, 0, 0, 0],[ 0,  0, 0, -1, 0, 0, 0, -1],[ 0,  0, 0, -1, 0, 0, -1, 0],[ 0,  0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0, 0],[ 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, -1, -1, 0],[ 0,  0, 0, 0, 0, -1, 0, -1]]
rhs_ineq = [-1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1, -1]
bnd = [(0, float("inf")),(0, float("inf")),(0, float("inf")),(0, float("inf")),(0, float("inf")),(0, float("inf")),(0, float("inf")),(0, float("inf"))] 
opt = linprog(c=obj, A_ub=lhs_ineq, b_ub=rhs_ineq, bounds=bnd, method="revised simplex")
print(opt)
```

What comes out is the following, which looks like the optimal solution even though it was done with LP.

```
     con: array([], dtype=float64)
     fun: 3.0
 message: 'Optimization terminated successfully.'
     nit: 11
   slack: array([0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.])
  status: 0
 success: True
       x: array([0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 1., 0., 0.])
```

The array in the output [0,1,0,1,0,1,0,0] represents a vertex cover with the nodes 2,4,6 which is also the optimal solution (the digit is 0 for a node not in the solution and 1 otherwise).